# Prevent MicroStrategy from running individual INSERTs in a temp table

Tags: microstrategy

I'm a SQL Server DBA tasked with improving performance of our MicroStrategy environment.  I have no training in MicroStrategy.

I have run SQL Server Profiler and captured a trace that shows a report that runs a query which MicroStrategy stores in a temp table for use in later queries.  For example:

```
--Obviously this isn't the real query - I don't think the exact query is important
--This runs in a couple seconds
select CUSTOM_GRP_ID, GRP_COLOR
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.id=t1.id

--MicroStrategy uses the result of the above query to do individual inserts
--Each of the individual insert statements take milliseconds to run, but there is a delay between the inserts
create table #TFMWZF78HOP000(
    CUSTOM_GRP_ID   INTEGER, 
    GRP_COLOR   VARCHAR(20));
insert into #TFMWZF78HOP000 values (101196, '#5BBDFF');
insert into #TFMWZF78HOP000 values (101278, '#F11BAA');
... Repeats thousands of times with different values
insert into #TFMWZF78HOP000 values (100532, '#808000');
insert into #TFMWZF78HOP000 values (101798, '#FBD0BE');
create index #TFMWZF78HOP000_i on #TFMWZF78HOP000 (CUSTOM_GRP_ID, GRP_COLOR) ;

--MicroStrategy then uses the #TFMWZF78HOP000 temp table in other queries
```

Some of the worst cases involve an initial query that returns 100K rows which are then individually inserted into a temp table.  This individual insert process takes several minutes rather than using a "SELECT INTO" method (which takes a couple seconds) like this:

```
select CUSTOM_GRP_ID, GRP_COLOR
into #TFMWZF78HOP000  --This inserts into a temp table as a set rather than individual inserts
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.id=t1.id
```

I know that MicroStrategy can use the above syntax because I have seen it in other queries.  Is there something that my developers can do to cause this single-insert method since it performs dramatically better?  They hesitate to use Freeform SQL because they say it will cause maintenance issues.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Typically this happens when a report has been created with a computation that can't be performed on the database directly, so MSTR will select the source data, perform the computation in its own analytical engine, and then insert the filtered/modified/aggregated data into a temp table to be used by later passes.

[Here is a vendor tech note](https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/KB19503-A-row-by-row-insert-into-temporary-tables-is-performed?language=en_US), albeit for a different RDBMS, that gives a scenario in which this can happen.

I would suggest going back the MicroStrategy developers to see if they can build the report to work in a different, more efficient way.

Comment: Thanks @paulbailey!  The developers believe the DB is configured properly.  Do you have any suggestions on how to "build the report to work in a different, more efficient way"?

Comment: Sadly, without looking at how the report is built, it’s hard to say. Filtering a report to only show the Top X, for example, can cause this behaviour. 

Fundamentally, the analytical engine is doing some sort of comparison on those rows before inserting them into the DB. That’s something in the definition of the report generating the SQL.